# Running Dokku with NodeJS and Prisma

Tags: prisma, dokku

While developing a NodeJS with Prisma application and deploying on Dokku, I was wondering what is the recommended approach to make database updates with Prisma, given the dokku closed build approach with Webpacks.

At the moment my approach is to connect to the postgres database remotely through the local node checkout. But would prefer to do this on the server for security reasons.